# Retrieve values from jQuery to C# Code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery script like this:

```
var sList = "";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
var sThisVal = (this.checked ? "1" : "0");
sList += (sList=="" ? sThisVal : "," + sThisVal);
});
console.log (sList);
```

But this script just writes sList values to console.
How can I retrieve sList values in C# code? and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="myList"/>
```

and write a JavaScript:

```
$("input[type=hidden][id$=myList]").val(sList);
```

and now you should get your `sList` on your `server events`, just see `myList.Value` from your `C# code`

Comment: Thank you, My reputation is not enough to score you.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, if you don't want to do a full postback, you could consider using the ASP.NET AJAX Server Callback mechanism.

This will allow you to send your sList to a server-side web service, do whatever server-side processing you want, and then return the JSON-encoded result to the client.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply add a hidden field to your asp.net page and set its value as a comma separated string using your JS function.

form the C# just get the data saved in the hidden field..