# How to sum values of checkboxlist and show the total amount?

Tags: drupal, checkboxlist

I have created a Drupal website with a new page for registration purposes. I would like to have a checkbox list of my provided services (for example back-up user files), with the corresponding prices next to each service.

When multiple checkboxes are checked, the values (in this case, the prices) need to sum up to a total amount. This amount then should be displayed on the page.

How can I sum the amounts associated with the checkboxes?

Comment: Use some javascript/php logic to sum the values

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce, but how do i attach the price to a specific checkbox ? So when that checkbox is selected, it will thake the price it is attatched to.

Comment: So what do you prefer? JS or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the checkbox value attribute to attach the price amount to a checkbox?
While submitting/processing use js/php logic to add the selected checkboxes.

Update:
options array should be like [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#options)

```
array('return_value1' => t('Display Value 1'), 'return_value2' => t('Display Value 2'))
```

Comment: Not exactly, i have found a way to make a array of checkboxes. And loop through the array to find whether a checkbox is check or not. But i still can't add the price as a value to the checkbox.

Comment: That works ! THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! I have used this code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965075/jquery-loop-through-checkboxes-and-count-each-one-checked-or-unchecked)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module.

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't see any other option then this one. Thanks for the help !