# jQuery loop through checkboxes that name attribute contain bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have these checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="6">
```

My question is via jquery, how would I loop through the ids[] on form submit?

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  //Loop throught ids[] 
});
```

I have tried this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=ids[]]').each(function () {   
  console.log("Here");
});
```

But it didn't work

Comment: What have you tried? What did work? And what did not?

Comment: Simple to target them by their class and loop over that collection using jQuery `each`. What exactly are you wanting to accomplish?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each  i feel like this question could have been answered with a simple google search.

Comment: I am looking for get each of the checked values in an array to loop through it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965075/loop-through-checkboxes-and-count-each-one-checked-or-unchecked#1965137

Comment: just google it. https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: `[name=ids[]]` is an invalid selector.  put double quotes around the `ids[]` to force it to be a literal.  But you don't have to do that.  Just select using your class.

Comment: Just tried that and it did't work

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/  Then you did it wrong.  `$('.ids')` will work fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through checkboxes and count each one checked or unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965075/loop-through-checkboxes-and-count-each-one-checked-or-unchecked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is invalid. You should escape `[]` with `\\`.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox][name=ids\\[\\]]').each(function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="5">
<input type="checkbox" class="ids" name="ids[]" value="6">
```